# Transfer DNS management to Route53 while keeping subdomain pointing to a different server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I need to transfer DNS management to AWS Route53 so I can host multiple Wordpress sites with different domains on a Lightsail instance using Plesk Obsidian. I've already set up one domain and its website. The next domain I need to setup for a Wordpress site that'll run on the Lightsail instance has an existing subdomain that's used for an app running on an EC2 instance. That EC2 instance's URL doesn't use a Route53 zone, i.e., it just has an A record that associates the subdomain to the EC2's static IP address.

My question is whether I need to create a Route53 zone for the subdomain after I move DNS record management to Route53, or is just keeping the A record for the subdomain in the Route53 DNS records sufficient without creating a separate Route53 zone?

Hopefully my question/concern makes sense. My concern stems from whether Route53 behaves like any other DNS manager or if it has peculiarities I need to be aware of for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd just have to learn by trial and error since no one answered.

I created the A record on Route53 to point to the subdomain and switched to AWS nameservers ... and voila, it worked without having to add the subdomain as a Route 53 zone. My security certificate even resumed working on the subdomain after a 10 minute period in which it couldn't find the CNAME record of the certificate issuer.

So long story short, Route53 works just fine for pointing to subdomains outside of the Route53 zone. One A record does the trick.